# Serialization "isolation level" in MongoDB, or the lost-update problem

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I realize MongoDB is a NoSQL solution, but I was wondering if it had some sort of equivalent to serialization-level transaction isolation level.

If not, how would you solve the lost-update problem in MongoDB?

I want to keep the revision history of some data in Mongo and each revision has to point to the one before it. How can I make sure no more than one latest revision exists for my data, and on the other hand that no revision is lost due to concurrent updates?

** Edit **

Oops, RTFM, it is indeed possible: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations

Not sure if I should close the question since the knowledge might be relevant to other people..

Comment: just more context: running on linux and not interested in solutions using file locking..

Comment: e.g. CouchDB has sort of optimistic locks where if an update uses an obsolete rev id it is rejected. That solves the problem. Not sure if Mongo has anything similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, so long as you keep the history in a single document.  MongoDB supports [atomic updates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) within the scope of a document, but not across multiple documents in a collection.

So, you could embed the history in an array, using a schema something like this:

```
{
    _id: 12345,
    value: "Apple",
    history:
    [
        { revisionid: 2, value: "Orange" },
        { revisionid: 1, value: "Pear" }
    ]
}
```

For example, you could insert a new document:

```
db.things.insert( { _id: 123, value: "Apple" } )
```

Then update it in one atomic operation:

```
db.things.update( { _id: 123 },
    {
        $set: { value: "Orange" },
        $push : { history : { revisionid: 1, value: "Apple" } }
    }
)
```

Comment: I think you would need to use findAndModify on later mongodb versions. The critical point to note is that there is a query part. So 2 or more of these update operations concurrently will lead to only one succeeding. The other will not match the query as it would have changed. I would have the query to include "value:apple"